# Primefaces Calendar getDate

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I need to use Primefaces Calendar's Client side API to getDate. Here is the sample code but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Primefaces 3.4.2, JSF 2.2, Glassfish 4

```
 <h:form id="calendarFormId">
        <p:calendar id="calendarId" mode="inline" value="#{eventController.eventUI.date}" widgetVar="calendarWidget">
        </p:calendar>
    </h:form>

    <script>
        var myDate = calendarWidget.getDate();
        alert(myDate);
    </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the actual output you get? Is `#{eventController.eventUI.date}` initially empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debuging your codesnippet in firefox got the following trace:

```
[13:24:47,383] ReferenceError: calendarWidget is not defined @ http://localhost:8080/labb1/index.xhtml:12
```

So drew the conclusion that the script is executed to early. One way to delay execution is to wait for page to be ready.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var myDate = calendarWidget.getDate();
        alert(myDate);
    });
</script>
```

see [how-to-execute-javascript-after-page-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996316/how-to-execute-javascript-after-page-load)

Comment: Thank you. document ready solved the problem. I feel so stupid not trying this before. Appreciate your help.