# How pass parameters to downstream function with done() or next()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to next(), done() etc. and am struggling with propagating parameters between serial executions/chaining of possibly otherwise asynchronous functions.

I want to force serial execution of 2 functions so they can be called with something like either:

```
f1('#{arg1a}', '#{arg1b}').done(
  f2('#{arg2a}', '#{arg2b}')
);
```

OR something like:

```
f1('#{arg1a}', '#{arg1b}', '#{arg2a}', '#{arg2b}').done(f2);
```

Where the arg values passed in are gleaned from query parameters using JSF.

Note that:

- `arg2a` and `arg2b` are in my case completely unrelated to `arg1a` and `arg1b`, and the invocation of `f2` does NOT depend in any way on what happens in `f1`, other than it must execute strictly afterwards, even if `f1` is otherwise usually asynchronous.
- I am not defining on-the-fly anonymous functions or such inside done() here (yet), I want to be able to call a library-defined function with some known params.

In this example, the functions would be something like:

```
function f1(arg1a, arg1b) {

   //do something with arg1a, arg1b

  return $.Deferred().resolve();
}

function f2(arg2a, arg2b) {
  // Do something with arg2a and arg2b AFTER f1 has fully run.
}
```

OR something like:

```
function f1(arg1a, arg1b, arg2a, arg2b) {

   //do something with arg1a, arg1b

  // Somehow ensure f1 is finished then execute f2(arg2a, arg2b)
}

function f2(arg2a, arg2b) {
  // Do something with arg2a and arg2b AFTER f1 has fully run.
}
```

Just using callback chaining did not work for the situation I am tackling. See also: [How link to and target/open a p:tab within an p:accordionPanel within a p:tab within a p:tabview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716981/jsf-primefaces-how-link-to-and-target-open-a-tab-within-an-accordionpanel-with)

*An acceptable answer MUST permit me to have a pre-defined function f2 with pre-defined parameters*

Comment: `return $.Deferred().resolve()` makes no sense because you're calling resolve synchronously in which case you wouldn't even need to handle this async. Are you using an asynchronous function inside `f1`?

Comment: Also, can you give a **synchronous** example of what you're trying to do. Something along the lines of "if this was synchronous I'd want to do this..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass parameters to `.resolve()`, then use `.then()`

```
function f1(arg1a, arg1b) {

  return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
    //do something with arg1a, arg1b
    // you can alternatively call `.resolve()` without passing parameters
    // when you are finished doing something with `arg1a`, `arg1b`,
    // which should call chained `.then()` where `f2` is called
    dfd.resolve(arg1a, arg1b)
  }).promise();
}

function f2(arg2a, arg2b) {
  // Do something with arg2a and arg2b AFTER f1 has fully run.
}

f1(arg1, arg2)
.then(function() {
  // call `f2` here
  f2('#{arg2a}', '#{arg2b}');
})
// handle errors
.catch(function(err) { // alternatively use `.fail()`
  console.log(err)
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wuy8pj8d/

Comment: I don't see how you've passed real values for arg2a and arg2b (to be ultimately handled by `f2`) into `f1(arg1, arg2).then(f2) ...`

Comment: _"I don't see how you've passed real values for arg2a and arg2b"_ What do you mean? You can pass any value that you need to to `.resolve()`

Comment: `arg2a` and `arg2b` are in my case completely unrelated to `arg1a` and `arg1b`. When you invoke `f1(arg1a,arg1b).then(f2) .. ` there is no moment where the values gleaned from say JSF parameters for arg2a, arg2b are injected. They don't even appear in your calling/invoking code.

Comment: _"arg2a and arg2b are in my case completely unrelated to arg1a and arg1b"_ Again, you can pass any value that you need to, or no value, to `.resolve()`; when `.resolve()` is called chained `.then()` is called with `f2` as parameter. You included parameters at `f2`, though they do not need to be the values returned from `f2` The values do not have to be `arg1a`, `arg1b`. The jsfiddle is to demonstrate pattern to meet requirement described at original Question _"the invocation of f2 does NOT depend in any way on what happens in f1, other than it must execute strictly afterwards"_

Comment: Thanks, accepted now you've edited it to correctly handle and demonstrate calling of additional arguments for feeding to `f2` (and so it makes sense for other readers to follow). I hit this `.then(...).catch is not a function` in my system, so I used `fail()` then it ran. The `then()` strategy does not solve [my real world app Primefaces nested tab problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716981/how-link-to-and-target-open-a-ptab-within-an-paccordionpanel-within-a-ptab-wi), but your solution enabled me to at least test the strategy (and learn more about then() and Promises).

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it right except you've forgotten to wrap the code you want to execute in the future (when `done` is eventually called) inside a function:

```
f1('#{arg1a}', '#{arg1b}').done(function(){
  f2('#{arg2a}', '#{arg2b}')
});
```

This also works with regular callbacks. For example, say you've defined `f1` to accept a callback instead of a promise, you'd then do:

```
f1('#{arg1a}', '#{arg1b}',function(){
  f2('#{arg2a}', '#{arg2b}')
});
```

Nothing special here. There's no separate syntax for forcing callbacks to accept custom arguments, just wrap it in another function.

This also works for variables thanks to closures:

```
var a='#{arg1a}', b='#{arg1b}';
var c='#{arg2a}', d='#{arg2b}';

f1(a,b).done(function(){
  f2(c,d)
});
```

The variables `c` and `d` will be accessible within `done()`.

Comment: Thanks for your alternative answer, which definitely (like the amended alread-accepted answer from @guest271314) makes the values for `f2` available to it fine. However, as with `next(` and the `callback` approach, in my [real problem involving a Primefaces web app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716981/how-link-to-and-target-open-a-ptab-within-an-paccordionpanel-within-a-ptab-wi), the `done(` after `f2` is running before `f1` is finishing, so certain selectors are failing (because they are not yet available for selection). But that's beyond the scope of this question here.

Comment: @WebelITAustralia-upvoter: The problem with that question is that you're calling the `callback` before whatever you're waiting for is done. Therefore it doesn't work. The point of a callback is so that you can pass it to the thing you are waiting for. If that thing does not provide you with a callback or promise then you have to resort to using `setTimeout` to poll the DOM and wait until the thing you're waiting for exist.